# Don't understand remapping

Tags: ros, c++, ros-kinetic, topics, remap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could someone explain me in details what the remapping is doing? And how it is working?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303611/don%27t-understand-remapping/) by [S.Yildiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/36516/s.yildiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2018-09-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From a really high-level: remapping makes the ROS middleware return a *different resource* when a *graph participant* asks for *a resource* with a certain name.

In other words: if there is a remap from `name_a` to `name_b` and `node_x` asks for `name_a`, it will actually be returned whatever is registered with `name_b`.

To make it more concrete (with two examples):

- for a publisher: if `node_x` wants to publish to topic `chatter`, but there is a remap `chatter->other_topic`, then it may advertise a `chatter` publisher, but it will actually be publishing to topic `other_topic`
- for a subscriber: if `node_x` subscribes to `chatter`, but there is a remap `chatter->other_topic`, it will request a subscription to `chatter`, but in reality it will subscribe to `other_topic`

These remaps are completely transparent (ie: invisible) to `node_x`, they are processed by the ROS middleware.

The "only requirement" is of course that `chatter` and `other_topic` are of the same message type. Remapping is not magic, it changes names, not types (that would be message *transformation*).

---

The power here is that I can write a `node_x` and you can write a `node_y` and we can both **hardcode** the topic names we want to use.

If we used different topic names, but one of our users wants to "connect" our two nodes together, they only have to provide a remapping. Either:

- make `node_x` use the topic name that `node_y` expects
- make `node_y` use the topic name that `node_x` expects
- remap both to a third name, different from what `node_x` and `node_y` use internally

---

Edit: you've probably already seen it, but just for completeness: see the [Remapping Arguments](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments) on the wiki for some more information.

And although it's an article about ROS 2, the [Remapping Names](https://design.ros2.org/articles/static_remapping.html) article on the ROS2 design website might provide some additional background. It also has a section on ROS 1 remapping.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7